# Get Visual Studio to recognize the jsx setting from the tsConfig,json

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, intellisense

I have a TypeScript/React project in Visual Studio.

The challenge is getting Visual Studio to recognize React.

IntelliSense errors in Visual Studio  are of the form -

```
“--jsx is not set”,  “Cannot use JSX,  unless  the  ‘—jsx’ flag  is provided”
```

The obvious solution is to configure   –-jsx.

There seems to be at least two way to do this -

- Visual Studio project , Project properties -> TypeScript Build 
  –>  JSX Compilation in TSX files
- tsConfig.json

  {
    "compilerOptions": {

  ```
  "jsx": "react",
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, 
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "target": "es5", ...
  ```

I have already configured  -–jsx  in tsConfig.json,  and the command line gulp build works just fine, but Visual Studio still thinks that –jsx is not set.

So, for Visual  Studio,  I figured I could just set the project property ( in addition to tsconfig.json) 
But in Visual Studio  this is disabled  -   “One or more tsconfig.json files detected. Project Properties are disabled”

[image]

How do I get Visual Studio to recognize the –jsx setting from the  tsConfig,json.  It seems to recognize that tsConfig.json exists , but does  not  specifically recognize that –jsx is configured

Dev Environment

- Visual  Studio: 2017 Professional
- TypeScript : 2.1.4
- React : 15.4.2

Comment: Hi Robotronic, please share the detail steps to get the IntelliSense errors in Visual Studio that you mentioned?

Comment: The grayed out settings page does not show the current configuration of your `tsConfig.json` file. So do not worry about what you see there.

Comment: Any update on this @Sara Lui-MSFT? I can easily reproduce this still now with the latest VS2017 Enterprise + latest updates.

Answer (score 2):

Historic question but still relevant today (at least to me...)

Solution: After setting `"jsx": "react"` in `tsConfig.json` **restart Visual Studio**.

Comment: lol classic 'restart visual studio' works